# Iterating through collection of elements in HTML blocks in InvisionPower Content

Tags: php, ipb

Let's say we're writing a IPContent block that is a HTML type.
I want to list elements from $results.

```
<php>
// ...
// getting db elements with classDb into $results

foreach($results as $result){</php>

{$result['id']}<br />

<php>}</php>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I know, that print, echo, print_r, var_dump etc are disabled and I know, that to output single value I should embrace it with {}.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As I researched topic a bit I came to a conclusion, that it is not possible for a programmer to make a loop described in my question (that is embedded in block).

However it can be done in templates (not blocks) with following syntax:

```
<foreach loop="optional_loop_name_of_your_liking:$results as $result">
    {$result}
</foreach>
```

or

```
<foreach loop="optional_loop_name_of_your_liking:$results as $key => $value">
    {$key} => {$value}
</foreach>
```

There are also other solutions that allow to print iterated elements in a block - first is to include a PHP file which execute a loop (you'll probably have you yield also HTML) or to embed PHP in block with , write to buffer and assign its content to a variable, then print that variable outside the php block.